# Show image in cell based on cell value

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I am creating a weekly income comparison table. I want to compare A5 and A10 cells and display appropriate image in B7 cell. The image will be either UP or DOWN arrow (which reflects increase or decrease).

I've created a formula which puts text up or down in the cell, but I don't know how to replace it with the up/down image.

```
=IF(D77>D69, "up", IF(D77<D69, "down"))
```

How can I do it? I know it's possible.

Note: I am using Google Docs Excel, so please let me know if this cannot be done in it, but I have to use the real Excel installed on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(D77>D69, "↑","↓")
```

Alt codes will do the trick! The codes can be checked [here](http://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/arrow-alt-codes.php) for some variations!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=IF(D77>D69, "#","$")
```

and format the cell with the **Wingdings 3** font.

Comment: This works in Excel, but not on cloud Excel. Also images are grey scale, not colored.